# element.ready vs angular.element($document).ready

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on a directive but I don't want to play with `$document` or `$window`, only with the `element` itself.

Before I had:

```
angular.element($document).ready(function() {...});
```

and was working, just a few minutes ago I changed, and put:

```
element.ready(function() {...});
```

and it is working also.

So, when I say `element.ready(function() {...})` am I telling Angular to run that function when the element `<my-directive></my-directive>` is ready?  or what am I doing?

I am asking this because I am wondering, why it is still working if I do `element.ready` instead.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need either.

`ready` isn't needed since element has to exist for link function to fire. Also there is no element level ready event ... it is only used at document level to account for full body of page existing. That stage is long over when angular is compiling directives.

You can do any manipulation or event binding directly to `element` immediately within `link` function of directive

Comment: For clarity, it should be the `post` link function (which is the default for `link: function() {...}`)

Comment: Yes its not necessary but by the way its same and not different

Answer (score -4):

In angularjs, `angular.element` is a jqLite object

And element in angular directive is a jqLite object and you dont need to wrap again with `angular.element`

for example in this code all elements is same

```
var element1 = angular.element( document.getElementById('test') ); // a jqLite object

var element2 = angular.element( element1 ); // same jqLite object

var element3 = angular.element( element2 ); // same jqLite object
```

By the way you don't need ready because directives links call when element ready